# Download zip file from the server and parsing it

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I am trying to download a zipped file from the server and trying to show the content of each files in zipped folder to the view.

I wrote a separate code where the file is on my laptop and I ran across each file and dislpayed the content such as

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string filePath = "C:\\ACL Data\\New folder\\files.zip";
     var zip= new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(filePath));
     var filestream=new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
     ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(filestream);
     ZipEntry item;
     while ((item = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
         using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(zipfile.GetInputStream(item)))
         {
             Console.WriteLine(s.ReadToEnd());
         }
     }
     Console.Read();
 }
```

I am using sharplibzip library to implement this
This is the case when the zip file is located locally in the system. My next task  scenario is what if the zipped file is located on the server. I am figuring out the way to implement it, below is the code what I assume should work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string url = "https://test/code/304fd9c6-7e53-42a2-845a-624608bfd2ce.zip";
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    var zip = new ZipInputStream(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
    ZipEntry item1;

    //var zip= new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(filePath));
    var filestream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(filestream);
    ZipEntry item;
    while ((item = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(zipfile.GetInputStream(item)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

I am stuck at this part:  `var filestream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`

This expect the first parameter to be path of the zip file. Since in the new scenario zip file is located remotely on the server. What should be the parameter in this case?

Comment: Can you not download the file to a temporary file, then handle that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code opens the stream twice on the following rows, which I think is causing some confusion:

```
var zip= new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(filePath));
var filestream=new FileStream(filePath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
```

There is an overload to the `ZipFile` constructor that takes "any" Stream rather than specifically a FileStream, which you - unsurprisingly - can only create for files.

However, you cannot use the stream returned by `GetResponseStream` directly, because it's `CanSeek` property is `false`. This is because it's a NetworkStream, which can only be read once from beginning to end. SharpZipLib needs random access to read the file contents.

Depending on the size of the ZIP file, loading it in memory may be an option. If you expect large files, writing it to a temporary file may be better.

This should do the trick, without using both `ZipInputStream` and `ZipFile`, by enumerating through ZipFile instead:

```
string url = "https://test/code/304fd9c6-7e53-42a2-845a-624608bfd2ce.zip";
WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();

using (var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Copy entire file into memory. Use a file if you expect a lot of data
    responseStream.CopyTo(ms);

    var zipFile = new ZipFile(ms);

    foreach (ZipEntry item in zipFile)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        using (var s = new StreamReader(zipFile.GetInputStream(item)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
Console.Read();
```

PS: starting .NET 4.5, there is support for ZIP files built in. See the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.